# Python Subtract cumulative column for Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a daily cumulative sum and I would like to break it down into daily values instead. It also needs to be grouped of course.

For example, I would like to take this dataframe and return the bellow result:

```
ID    Date            Cum Value
3306  2019-06-01      100.0 
3306  2019-07-01      200.0 
3306  2019-08-01      350.0
4408  2019-06-01      200.0
4408  2019-07-01      375.0
4408  2019-08-01      400.0

ID    Date           Cum Value  Daily Value
3306  2019-06-01      100.0     100.0
3306  2019-07-01      200.0     100.0
3306  2019-08-01      350.0     150.0
4408  2019-06-01      200.0     200.0
4408  2019-07-01      375.0     175.0
4408  2019-08-01      400.0     025.0
```

I have tried

```
df['Daily Value'] = df['Cum Value'].sub(df['Cum Value'].shift())
df['Daily Value'].iloc[0] = df['Cum Value'].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Why is the `Cum Value` column different in the second example? Shouldn't it be `-150` for the value next to the second `200`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need [`groupby+diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and `fillna`:

```
df['Daily Value']=df.groupby('ID')['Cum Value'].diff().fillna(df['Cum Value'])
print(df)
```

---

```
     ID        Date  Cum Value  Daily Value
0  3306  2019-06-01      100.0        100.0
1  3306  2019-07-01      200.0        100.0
2  3306  2019-08-01      350.0        150.0
3  4408  2019-06-01      200.0        200.0
4  4408  2019-07-01      375.0        175.0
5  4408  2019-08-01      400.0         25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) + [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)

```
df['Daily Value']=df['Cum Value'].sub(df.groupby('ID')['Cum Value'].shift(fill_value=0))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     ID        Date  Cum Value  Daily Value
0  3306  2019-06-01      100.0        100.0
1  3306  2019-07-01      200.0        100.0
2  3306  2019-08-01      350.0        150.0
3  4408  2019-06-01      200.0        200.0
4  4408  2019-07-01      375.0        175.0
5  4408  2019-08-01      400.0         25.0
```

> I think it could be faster